# Is there a way to use the output of a given (middle) layer in Keras as the input of another network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Is there a way to use the output of a given (middle) layer in Keras as the input of another network?

For example use the last dense layer of the encoder here as the input for another network?

```
#encoder
encoder = keras.models.Sequential()
encoder.add(L.InputLayer(img_shape))
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),strides=1, padding='same', activation='elu'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),strides=1, padding='same', activation='elu'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3),strides=1, padding='same', activation='elu'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3),strides=1, padding='same', activation='elu'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Flatten())
encoder.add(L.Dense(code_size))


    # decoder
decoder = keras.models.Sequential()
decoder.add(L.InputLayer((code_size,)))
decoder.add(L.Dense(147456))
decoder.add(L.Reshape((24, 24, 256)))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation=None, padding='same'))
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new network where the output of the encoder is the input of the decoder?

Comment: I am going to use the output of the encoder as the input for a network that approximates a vector of the same size that is the output of the same autoencoder, but with a different dataset.

Comment: so the decoder isn't actually relevant?

Comment: I will eventually use the vector that is to be approximated with a decoder. The idea is to predict one image given another. So if I can approximate what the encoding for a different input would be, I could just decode that approximation.

Comment: So you want to create a new network where the input is passed through the encoder and then is decoded into a different image?

Comment: The plan is: Run1: Lean an encoding for one image set. Run2: Learn an encoding for another corresponding image set. Run3: Learn encoding 2 given encoding 1. Run 4: given first image input and learned corresponding encoding for the second input, decode to produce image matching second input.

Comment: Okay there are much more robust ways to solve that than your four step plan. You are trying to make an pix-2-pix encoder-decoder but you're trying to do train each part separately. You can do everything in one step. Check out CycleGan: https://github.com/junyanz/CycleGAN

Comment: I think the functional API is what you look for.  https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/  In short, you can do something like `encoded = encoder(x); decoded = decoder(encoded)`, to use `encoder` to transform your data and feed it into `decoder`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the encoding layers of your network as an input *(i.e you don't want to change the weights of your encoder network through backpropagation when training the rest of your model)* you can just get the outputs of the last layer of your decoder network using the `predict_generator` method on you keras model, for all of your examples and use that as input data for your predictor network.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this

```
decoder = keras.models.Sequential()(encoder)
```